# Calling a PL/SQL constructor with default values and named parameters

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, syntax-error

In Oracle 11g I've got the following type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_XMLTABLE" AS OBJECT (
 zeile NUMBER,
 spalte NUMBER,
 wert VARCHAR2(1000),
 xml NUMBER,
 link VARCHAR2(1000),
 target VARCHAR2(100),
 srt NUMBER,
 typ NUMBER,
 format VARCHAR2(100),
 uebersetzbar NUMBER,
 tooltip VARCHAR2(100),
 kommentar NUMBER,
 output NUMBER,

 CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_xmltable(p_zeile        NUMBER,
                                 p_spalte       NUMBER,
                                 p_wert         VARCHAR2,
                                 p_xml          NUMBER,
                                 p_link         VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_target       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_srt          NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                 p_typ          NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
                                 p_format       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_uebersetzbar NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                 p_tooltip      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_kommentar    NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                 p_output       NUMBER DEFAULT 7) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_xmltable AS
 CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_xmltable(p_zeile        NUMBER,
                                 p_spalte       NUMBER,
                                 p_wert         VARCHAR2,
                                 p_xml          NUMBER,
                                 p_link         VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_target       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_srt          NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                 p_typ          NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
                                 p_format       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_uebersetzbar NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                 p_tooltip      VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                 p_kommentar    NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                 p_output       NUMBER DEFAULT 7) RETURN SELF AS RESULT 

AS
     BEGIN
       self.zeile        := p_zeile;
       self.spalte       := p_spalte;
       self.wert         := p_wert;
       self.xml          := p_xml;
       self.link         := p_link;
       self.target       := p_target;
       self.srt          := p_srt;
       self.typ          := p_typ;
       self.format       := p_format;
       self.uebersetzbar := p_uebersetzbar;
       self.tooltip      := p_tooltip;
       self.kommentar    := p_kommentar;
       self.output       := p_output;
       RETURN;
     END;
    END;
```

As you can see, it's got quite some members, which are initialized via the constructor with default values. Before we've got the constructor, the type was initiated like this:

```
t_xmltable(zeile        => v_y,
           spalte       => v_x,
           wert         => 'someval',
           xml          => 1337,
           link         => NULL,
           target       => NULL,
           srt          => 0,
           typ          => 1,
           format       => NULL,
           uebersetzbar => 1,
           tooltip      => NULL,
           kommentar    => 0,
           output       => 7);
```

Now, I introduced the constructor to get rid of the unnecessary default values. But it seems, that these default values can't be used in conjunction with named parameters. I don't really want to lose the comfort of them and it would be quite some work to refactor all the code that uses the type.

The following works:

```
DECLARE
  x t_xmltable;
BEGIN
  x := t_xmltable(1, 1, 'a', 1);
END;
```

The following not:

```
DECLARE
  x t_xmltable;
BEGIN
  x := t_xmltable(zeile => 1, spalte => 1, wert => 'a', xml => 1);
END;
```

Has someone got some ingenious ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Why close the question rather than accept an answer? (Przemyslaw got there slightly before me, annoyingly *8-) It's not quite a just-a-typo question, IMO, though I suppose it's arguably close...

Comment: Hm, you're right. Accepted @Przemyslaw's answer. Thanks once more ;)

Comment: @Alex Poole Yea, I didn't think answering to questions on this site would have this "thrill" factor to them :) each time I send an answer I wonder if anyone hasn't sent one before me ;) Joshua, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the error message?

Shouldn't the code be like this:

```
DECLARE
  x t_xmltable;
BEGIN
  x := t_xmltable(p_zeile => 1, p_spalte => 1, p_wert => 'a', p_xml => 1);
END;
```

(with p_ prefix for each of the named parameters)?

Answer (score 2):

Your named parameters have to match the parameter names in the constructor, not the underlying object field names:

```
DECLARE
  x t_xmltable;
BEGIN
  x := t_xmltable(p_zeile => 1, p_spalte => 1, p_wert => 'a', p_xml => 1);
END;
/

anonymous block completed
```

Alternatively, remove the `p_` prefix from the constructor parameter names - you don't need them, it won't be confused during the assignment. I can think of at least one contributor who I think would prefer that.